# How to append functions to current module from unrelated script in Python

Tags: python

I have two python scripts in different locations. I try to import the functions of the second one in such a way that they are integrated with the globals of the first one. That works fine. However when I call functions in the first script from the second one they cant be found.

foo.py

```
def run():
    glob = {}
    loc = {}
    execfile("/path/to/bar.py", glob, loc)
    currmodule = globals() 
    currmodule["func_in_bar"] = glob["func_in_bar"]
    func_in_bar()

def func_in_foo_A():
    print("fooA")

def func_in_foo_B():
    print("fooB")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

bar.py

```
def func_in_bar():
    func_in_foo_A()
    func_in_foo_B()
```

When foo is run it fails with: `NameError: global name 'func_in_foo_A' is not defined`

Comment: `glob = loc = {}` might not be a good idea as you then share the same dict for both scopes

Comment: right, not using loc anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bar.py` you need to add an `import foo` and then reference `foo.func_in_foo()`, etc.

Alternatively, use the form: `from foo import func_in_foo`

Comment: Whoeha. I assumed that would not work since bar is at a other location where it cant see foo. But foo is on the path of course so this works like a charm!